# There are $n$ families with $m$ members each sitting at a circular table. What is the expected number of "happy" people?

Tags: probability

> There are $n$ families with $m$ members each sitting at a circular table. Someone is happy if they are sitting next to a family member. What is the expected number of happy people?

What I did: let $X$ be the number of happy people. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^{nm} \chi_i$ where $\chi_i$ is $1$ if person $i$ is happy and $0$ else. Then $E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{nm} E(\chi_i)$. We can compute $E(\chi_i)=P(\text{person } i\text{ is happy})=1-\frac{nm-(m-1)}{nm-1}\frac{nm-(m-1)-1}{nm-2}$. Then we just sum from $i=1$ to $nm$.

Is this right? It seems off because the probabilities are dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe $$E(\chi_i)  = 1-{{nm-m\choose2}\over{nm-1\choose2}}={nm-m\over nm-1}\cdot {nm-m-1\over nm-2}$$  In the numerator, we must choose $2$ who are not in person $i$'s family.  There are $nm-m$ such people.

Other than that, your calculation is correct.  Linearity of expectation does not depend on independence of the events.  (If you think of the definition of expectation as an integral, this is obvious.)